# How can I trigger the loading animation of a WinJS ListView

Tags: windows-8, winjs, winrt-async

is there a way to trigger the loading animation of a ListView manually?

I load some data on start up from a web service and would like to display a busy indecator.

```
 function searchData(url) {

        var promise = DataService.getData(query);

        promise.done(function (result) {
            console.dir(result);
            var bindingList = new WinJS.Binding.List(result);

            sectionListView.winControl.itemDataSource = bindingList.dataSource;

        });
    }
```

this is what I do in app.onactivated

```
promise = WinJS.UI.processAll();
        promise.done(function () {
            searchData(query);
        });
        args.setPromise(promise);
```

I read something that ListView should display busy animation while waiting for a promise...
Is this true?
Or is this something I have to do manually... display and hide a div whenever needed?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 1):

[According to this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/1983e2cc-7ee5-440a-95f0-ee3e2e240bd9), the progress ring will only appear if the ListView is hooked up to an asynchronous data source, while the `WinJS.Binding.List` is synchronous. I don't think there are any asynchronous data sources available by default, so you would have to set up a custom data source to be able to get that default progress ring. I would recommend just setting a progress ring to run when your app starts and removing it in the `done` block of your data promise.

Comment: Do you have an example? Because I have a service with an async method and I am binding the result as binding list because I thought this is what ListView wants/needs. How would look the async data source?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own [custom List Data Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770849.aspx). WinJS provides the utilities to do this pretty easily. [This is a good sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ListView-custom-data-4dcfb128) against the Bing web service. If you need more samples of how to write your own Data Source / Data Adapter let me know, I've written a few.